# How do I create dynamically left div image height equal to right div height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is two div in each column, first div have image and second div have content. what do i want if right div content increased then left div image should be increase.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<a> <img src="image name" /></a>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-8">
<span>content </span>
<span>content</span>
</div>
enter code here
</div>
</div>
```

[image: See image snapshot:]

Comment: I cant see the two divs '

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like this, then you can use html tables. 
It will be easy to setup an image in tables so when the content increases then the image(s) will do the sane.

**Code**

```css
td {
  width: 50%;
}
#image {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <body>
    <table border="1px solid" width="500px" cellpadding=10px cellspacing=0>
      <tr>
        <td id="image"></td>
        <td>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>There is some text in this field.
          <br/>


        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I have tested this code and works ok. Change the background-image url with your own image url

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If u want to set height of image on document ready then use following code

```js
$(function(){
var getdivheight = $('.content').height();
$('.flexdiv img').height(getdivheight);
});
```

```css
.contnr{background: lightgray;padding:15px !important;}
.flexdiv{
    background: #ffffff;
}
.row{margin: 0px !important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div class="contnr container">
<div class="row">
<div class="flexdiv flexdivimg col-xs-6">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQclrVST8RfqvxSo5ggL8Ubn2_heNqVgJAxQYRDyigKqP0xnjRLS81yMFc" height="100%" width="100%" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="flexdiv content col-xs-6" contenteditable="">The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brownfox jumps over the lazy dog. </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If u certified with this code please vote once to grow up my reputation, which is needed.

Comment: Hi! There is another issue suppose we have five column, some column have less content and some column have more content. but here is all left column is increasing according to first right column. i want increase every column unique.